# Sticky Banner doesn't work properly on iOS browsers

Tags: html, ios, slider, position, sticky

I'm stuck with a rendering issue on iOS devices.

I have a **main_banner** with a sticky position, when I try to scroll down with an iOS device, it should be overlapped by the **columns** and **news** divs, this behaviour works as expected on other devices except iOS, which sometimes the banner is not rendered correctly.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.main_banner {
    height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
}
.main_banner {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    height: calc(100vh - 20vh);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
}

.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.news {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.news {
    padding: 2em 3em;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg,#e7dec1,transparent 11%),linear-gradient(45deg,#c7baaa,#dbc2af,#759798,#e0d9bd,transparent 36%),#f0e5cc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
```

With other OS like Android, Windows or even MacOS I don't have this problem.

[Screenshot iOS issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXi1X.jpg)

[Expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWK4m.jpg)

The website I'm developing is: https://www.fedebaljudo.com

The only "solution" I can apply so far is set a position: relative on **main_banner**

Anyone knows how can I fix this problem for iOS devices?

Thank you

Tried with iOS Simulator to check the problem, the rendering it auto-solves itself after a few seconds, but the problem persists.

Expected to get the same behaviour as the other devices.